# React | TypeScript - Context of "this" onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, tslint

**In the context below, what would be the proper way to assign** `this`?

The following react functional component calls and executes my `append()` method accordingly.

```
export const Guess: React.SFC<{}> = () => {
  const hero = "Spider";
  const animal = "Spider";

  function append() {
    return hero === animal ? "yes" : "no";
  };
  return <p>Are they similar? {append()}</p>;
};
```

However, when trying to call the method `onClick`, and modifying the function to:

```
export const Guess: React.SFC<{}> = () => {
  const hero = "Spider";
  const animal = "Spider";

  const append = () => () => {
    return hero === animal ? "yes" : "no";
  };

  return <p onClick={this.append()}>Are they similar? </p>;
};
```

I get a TS error:
`The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this' which implicitly has type 'any'`

I read that Arrow functions do not have lexical contexts, so any invocation of `this` inside the body of an arrow will degenerate to its value in the outer scope.

However, I'm not able to find the solution for this (pun intended :)

**Update:** Based on some of the comments below, I refactored the code to:

```
export const Guess: React.SFC<{}> = () => {
  const hero = "Spider";
  const animal = "Spider";

  function append() {
    console.log(hero === animal);
    return hero === animal ? 'yes' : 'no';
  }

  return <p onClick={append}>Are they similar? </p>;
};
```

Comment: arrow functions changes `this` value, you should avoid it using it with react

Comment: yes indeed, do you know how could I go about appropriately solving that issue?

Comment: use a normal function: `() => {` to `function() {`

Comment: To resolve the issue of using arrow functions when you shouldn't is by simply not using arrow functions. You can define a function with `= function() { ... };`

Comment: Do you mean `function append() { ... }` ? it errors: `Cannot read property 'append' of undefined` and the `TS` error for `this` remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fix

```
export const Guess: React.SFC<{}> = () => {
  const hero = "Spider";
  const animal = "Spider";

  const append = () => () => {
    return hero === animal ? "yes" : "no";
  };

  return <p onClick={this.append()}>Are they similar? </p>;
};
```

Should be:

```
export const Guess: React.SFC<{}> = () => {
  const hero = "Spider";
  const animal = "Spider";

  const append = () => () => {
    return hero === animal ? "yes" : "no";
  };

  return <p onClick={append}>Are they similar? </p>;
};
```

## More

Simplification : `this` is for classes. You have a function. You don't need to use `this` as you do not have an instance.

Also `onClick` takes a function. The expression `append()` is not a function. The expression `append` *is a function*.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer and explanation, Are we missing `( )`  on the suggested refactoring?, also I applied your suggested changes but nothing triggers on click: please see sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/lpz83843o7

Comment: It's because `this` is [lexically bound](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26).

Comment: @ErikPhilips could you please post an answer?

Comment: @basarat by doing as you suggested, nothing happens after the click event.